# Wifi Not detecting in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, connection

I have a HP 15 AC122TU laptop having dual OS as Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 8.1.My problem is that it doesn't detect wifi sometimes. If connection established it may result in a low speed and poor range. No such problem in other Operating System.Please help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of the command form the previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

Just disconnect, wait for a minute, and then just reconnect. I know it's annoying, but it works for me. Other than that, you may need patience and wait for Ubuntu to find a stability patch for that. This type of situation happens more often to me after i use Win8.1, and then switch to Ubuntu.